# C : wrong char to ascii conversion (char from the extended ascii table)

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, ascii, eclipse-cdt

I get the ascii code from a char like this (using C langage):

```
char * text = "5°"; 
int sizeText = strlen(text);
int i = 0;
float asciiCode;
for(i=0; i<sizeText; i++) {
    asciiCode = (GLfloat)text[i];
}
```

It's working well for the ASCII table (chars number 0 to 127) but it's not working with characters from the extended ASCII table. 
For example I get -62 from this symbol "°" (it should be 248).

I tried with several encoding like UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 (I'm using eclipse cdt btw), I got a different ASCII code each time but not the good one :/

Do you have any idea why it is not working? How can I get it work?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you displaying the values? Why are you assigning an ASCII code to a `float`? If I do `printf("5°")` it works just fine. The problem is you're assigning a signed character `248` (which is equivalent to -62 as a number) to a `float` which is keeping it as `-62` and now it's just a number..

Comment: You don't know for sure that "it should be 248". The signed-ness of `char` is platform dependent.

Comment: why in hell would you use a "graphic type" like GLfloat to manage char values which are moreover integers

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
GLfloat is a float, use an int didn't solve the problem (even if i agree it's better), using the type wchar_t did! 
Now I get 176 as ascii code of "°", i'm wondering where -62 is coming from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because char is from -127 to 127. You can't use extended ASCII table like that.

I suggest you use `wchar` instead. Check `wchar.h` and `wctype.h` manual.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that assiiCode is a float, try declaring it as an unsigned int